# Convergent subnet of a sequence and subsequential limit in a metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in a metric space $\mathbb{C}$. We know that $(x_n)$ is a net with the directed set being $\mathbb{N}$ equipped with the natural ordering. Suppose that $(x_\alpha)$ is a subnet of $(x_n)$ that converges to some $x_0$. Then can we construct a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converging to $x_0$. This is not true in a general topological space. However, here we have $\mathbb{C}$ which is a metric space.

If the answer is yes, then what is the reason behind it? Why it differs in a general topological space. I would like to request for hint or answers to find an explicit construction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The third sentence is confused?  Your are asking for a subsequence of $(x_n)$, but this seems to have nothing to do with $(x_\alpha)$???  Also, your choice of notation is poor.  You should probably use $(z_\alpha)$ instead of $(x_\alpha)$.  And the whole question is confusing. (Also, do you mean to work in the complex numbers?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that $\def\N{\mathbb N}\def\C{\mathbb C}\let\leq=\leqslant \let\geq=\geqslant\C$, or any metric space $X$, is first countable, meaning that every $x \in X$ has a countable basis of neighborhoods $\{U_n\}_{n\in\N}$, since we can take $U_n := B(x,\frac1n)$ for each $n\in\N$.

So if $x_{\alpha}$ is a subnet of $x_n$, and $x_\alpha \to x$, we can construct a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ as follows. Take $n_0 := 1$, and for each $k \in \N$ take $\alpha$ such that $\alpha > n_{k-1}$ (possible since subnets are cofinal by definition) and $x_\alpha \in U_n$ (possible since we assume $x_\alpha \to x$), and define $n_k := \alpha$. We have that $(n_k)_{k\in\N}$ is increasing and $x_{n_k} \to x$, so it's a convergent subsequence.

On the other hand, if $X$ is not first countable you can't do this. For an example, take $K := [0,1]^\N$ and $X := [0,1]^K$. $X$ is compact by Tychonov. Define $x_n \in X$ by $x_n := (f_n)_{f\in K}$. It has a convergent subnet by compactness. But suppose it had a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k} \to x$. For any $f\in K$ we must have $x_{n_k}(f) \to x(f)$, i.e., $f(n_k) \to x(f)$. Take any $f\in K$ such that $f(n_k)$ doesn't converge, say $f(n_k) := 1$ if $k$ is even, $f(n) := 0$ otherwise, and we get a contradiction.